# Como puedo saber que array es mayor y menor?

Tags: java, array

Tengo un codigo que guarda 10 calificaciones en un vector y al momento de sacar la calificacion mayor y la calificacion menor, solo la mayor la imprime y la menor me da como resultado 0

Codigo:

```
  Scanner entrada= new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] calificacion = new int[11];

    double suma = 0;
    double promedio;
    int w;
    int mayor=0;
    int menor=0;
    
    for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++) {

   
            System.out.print("ingresa la calificacion "+i+": " );
            calificacion[i]=entrada.nextInt();
          
                suma += calificacion[i];
    }
    
    for(int i=0;i<11;i++){
        if(calificacion[i]>mayor){
            mayor= calificacion[i];
        }
        else if(calificacion[i]<menor){
            menor= calificacion[i];
        }
    }
    promedio = suma / 10;
    System.out.println("El promedio es: "+promedio);

    System.out.println("La calificacion mayor es: "+mayor);
    System.out.println("La calificacion menor es: "+menor);
```

Comment: Tienes dos errores. Inicializa `menor` en `Integer.MAX_VALUE` porque si lo inicializas en 0, cuando hagas la comparación no habrá un número menor. El otro error que tienes se da recorriendo el array. Todos los campos del array se iniciarán en 0 y si no estableces algún campo lo tomará como que pusiste un 0 en ese espacio. Usa `calificacion.length` en tus ciclos para saber el tamaño del array y para sacar el promedio, de otro modo cuando quieras cambiar el tamaño del arreglo vas a tener cambiar todos los demás números que dependen de él y es muy fácil que olvides o se te pase uno.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Arrays.sort(calificacion);
```

Ordenas el arreglo de menor a mayor usando el **método sort()**. Al estar ordenado de menor a mayor quiere decir que el primer elemento es el menor y el último el mayor, por tanto:

```
int menor = calificacion[0];
int mayor = calificacion[9];
```

Ahora imprimes las **variables menor** y **mayor**. Recuerda que en **Java** la primera posición es la **0** no la **1**.